# SQL Server: Why does FORMAT return an empty string when the parameter is a zero?

Tags: sql, sql-server, formatting, string-formatting, sql-server-2017

I'm dealing with a weird bug, when converting numbers to text.

Whenever the number is zero, `FORMAT` returns an empty string, instead of `'0'`

Is there a reason for this behavior?
Am I using the `FORMAT` function incorrectly?

```
SELECT FORMAT ( 1 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '1' */

SELECT FORMAT ( 1E0 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '1' */

SELECT FORMAT ( 1.0 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '1' */

SELECT FORMAT ( 0 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '' */

SELECT FORMAT ( 0E0 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '' */

SELECT FORMAT ( 0.0 , N'#.######################' )  /* result '' */
```

`#.#####` produces exactly the style we need, so we'd like to keep that if possible.

As a workaround, I'm manually checking for zeros - but this is annoying, and kinda unscalable.

Comment: Specify a zero in the least significant place (e.g.  '###0').

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use `FORMAT` in the first place, ithas terrible performance; especially when compared to things like `CONVERT` with a style code. Such things should really be done in the present ation layer though, not at the DBMS.

Comment: @Larnu Point taken. This is not for performance-sensitive production activity though. Rather, it's a framework for dev-testing and reporting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#` doesn't fill in zeroes while `0` does. I think what you want is:

```
SELECT FORMAT ( 0 , N'0.######################' )
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings